# Simple python if statement

Tags: python

Sorry for asking a very simple question. I'm trying to teach myself python which seems pretty easy but I get stuck on some things.

```
x = input("Enter a number: ")

if x > 10 & x < 20:
   print "YES!!!"

else:
   print "Not between 10 and 20"
```

In C (pseudocode) I would do

```
if(x > 10 && x < 20)
     "yes"
else
     "no"
```

and it would work.. but in Python it just keeps printing out YES!!! no matter what I input. What am I doing wrong?

When I run it:

```
Enter a number: 3
YES!!!
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Enter a number: 13
YES!!!
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Enter a number: 6
YES!!!
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Enter a number: 13
YES!!!
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Enter a number: 4
YES!!!
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Enter a number: 8
Not between 10 and 20
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Enter a number: 13
YES!!!
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Enter a number: 3
YES!!!
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Enter a number: 8
Not between 10 and 20
```

Comment: @arshajii: Wouldn't Python 3.x require parentheses around the argument to `print`?

Comment: @KeithThompson That's right, I just realized that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`&` is the *bitwise* "and" operator in python. What you want is the logical "and", which is just the keyword: `and`.

```
if x > 10 and x < 20:
```

---

**---Pedantic Explanation---**

Now, if that were the only issue at play, you'd actually be fine, since Python `True` and `False` are just `1` and `0`. However, there's something else going on that actually causes the problem. Specifically, the bitwise operators have higher precedence than the comparison operators. As a result, Python sees (for example, if `x = 5`) `5 > 10 & 5 < 20` and parses it as `5 > (10 & 5) < 20`, which is a [chained comparison](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in). This is further expanded to:

```
(5 > (10 & 5)) and ((10 & 5) < 20)
```

Which evaluates to `True`, since `10 & 5` is zero:

```
(5 > 0) and (0 < 20)
True
```

Notice that `10 & 8` evaluates to `8`, which is why when you input `8` you get the "correct" result of not satisfying the condition (since 8 is not less than 8 for the first condition):

```
(8 > (10 & 8)) and ((10 & 8) < 20)
(8 > 8) and (8 < 20)
False
```

Comment: This is primarily important here because of precedence; `x > 10 & x < 20` is interpreted as the [chained comparison](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in) `x > (10 & x) < 20`.

Comment: And unlike in most other languages, `10 < x < 20` is equivalent to `x > 10 and x < 20`. (Don't try that in C; it's legal but has a completely different meaning.)

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah; I'm editing in a clarification to that effect as we speak :-)

Answer (score 1):

Operator & is binary operator. You probably want to use 'and' logical operator.

example: (a and b) is true.

Replace '&' for 'and'.

Answer (score 1):

In Python you need to use the Boolean operators `and` and `or` to combine Boolean expressions, not `&`, `|`, or any other variant involving those characters:

```
if x > 10 and x < 20:
   print "YES!!!"
else:
   print "Not between 10 and 20"
```

In this case you can also shorten it a bit:

```
if 10 < x < 20:
```

As for what is happening with your current code, `&` is a bitwise "and" operator, and it has higher operator precedence than comparisons so you are ending up with `x > (10 & x) < 20` which is equivalent to `(x > (10 & x)) and ((10 & x) < 20)`.  Obviously this is pretty far from what you are trying to do, but as it turns out this won't always evaluate to True, it evaluates to False if `x` is a negative number, `0`, `2`, `8`, or `10`.

Answer (score 0):

Logical AND in python is `and` keyword, not `&`. That's bitwise and operation.